# How to generate javadoc comments in Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, javadoc

**Can I use shortcut keys in Android studio to generate javadoc comments?**

If not, what is the easiest way to generate javadoc comments?

Comment: This question is 50/50. You ar eeither looking for single javadoc blocks of generating javadoc throughout the document. Which is it?

Comment: ALTR + ENTER show the view you can generate the comment of already declared methods.

Comment: May be you should add a Live template(Android studio - setting - editor - Live Templates - add)for it. In the template text field add the following text.
/**
 * $comment$
 */

Answer (score 434, accepted):

I can't find any shortcut to generate javadoc comments. But if you type `/**` before the method declaration and press Enter, the javadoc comment block will be generated automatically.

Read [this](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/working-with-code-documentation.html#add-new-comment) for more information.

Comment: It's a shame that this doesn't also work to generate javadoc comments for classes, fields, etc. It would be even nicer if it generated javadoc from a customizable template.

Comment: of course it has shortcut: position on method/constructor name and press alt+enter, choose generate javadoc from menu

Comment: refer [this](https://tips.androidhive.info/2015/04/how-to-auto-generate-comments-for-your-android-functions-android-studio/) more about above solution

Comment: @Ewoks [Doesn't work](https://i.imgur.com/Fnuwk0K.png) for me.

Answer (score 124):

To generatae comments type `/**` key before the method declaration and press `Enter`. It will generage javadoc comment.

Example:

```
/**
* @param a
* @param b
*/

public void add(int a, int b) {
    //code here
}
```

For more information check the link
https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/features/javadoc.html

Comment: @satheeshwaran - for what it's worth, I can see that just seeing the example of the comments (in the answer) is useful, when one wants an answer quickly ;-)

Comment: Actually the example lacks an * before the last /

Comment: Kotlin support: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40574195/generate-kdoc-for-methods-in-android-studio.

Answer (score 45):

Here is [an example of a JavaDoc comment from Oracle](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/index-137868.html):

```
/**
 * Returns an Image object that can then be painted on the screen. 
 * The url argument must specify an absolute {@link URL}. The name
 * argument is a specifier that is relative to the url argument. 
 * <p>
 * This method always returns immediately, whether or not the 
 * image exists. When this applet attempts to draw the image on
 * the screen, the data will be loaded. The graphics primitives 
 * that draw the image will incrementally paint on the screen. 
 *
 * @param  url  an absolute URL giving the base location of the image
 * @param  name the location of the image, relative to the url argument
 * @return      the image at the specified URL
 * @see         Image
 */
 public Image getImage(URL url, String name) {
        try {
            return getImage(new URL(url, name));
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            return null;
        }
 }
```

The basic format can be auto generated in either of the following ways:

- Position the cursor above the method and type `/**` + <kbd>Enter</kbd>
- Position the cursor on the method name and press <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> > click Add JavaDoc
  [image]

Comment: I came here because I knew this method from PhpStorm but in Android Studio it [doesn't work](https://i.imgur.com/Fnuwk0K.png).

Comment: Is there any shortcut to Add Javadoc to all the methods in the class ???

Answer (score 18):

You can install JavaDoc plugin from Settings->Plugin->Browse repositories.

get plugin documentation from the below link

[JavaDoc plugin document](https://github.com/setial/intellij-javadocs/wiki)

[image]

Comment: This works great. Install JavaDoc plugin (as above), then press CNTL + SHIFT + ALT + G.

Comment: for kotlin refer the following link https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/kotlin-doc.html

Comment: For Kotlin: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40574195/generate-kdoc-for-methods-in-android-studio.

Answer (score 12):

Javadoc comments can be automatically appended by using your IDE's autocomplete feature. Try typing `/**` and hitting <kbd>Enter</kbd> to generate a sample Javadoc comment.

```
 /**
 *
 * @param action          The action to execute.
 * @param args            The exec() arguments.
 * @param callbackContext The callback context used when calling back into JavaScript.
 * @return
 * @throws JSONException
 */
```

Answer (score 10):

You can use eclipse style of JavaDoc comment generation through "Fix doc comment".
Open "Preference" -> "Keymap" and assign "Fix doc comment" action to a key that you want.

Answer (score 9):

Here we can some something like this.
And instead of using any shortcut we can write "default" comments at class/ package /project level. And modify as per requirement

```
   *** Install JavaDoc Plugin ***



     1.Press shift twice and  Go to Plugins.
     2. search for JavaDocs plugin
     3. Install it. 
     4. Restart Android Studio.
     5. Now, rightclick on Java file/package and goto 
        JavaDocs >> create javadocs for all elements
        It will  generate all default comments.
```

Advantage is that, you can create comment block for `all the methods at a time.`

Answer (score 5):

In Android Studio you don't need the plug in. On A Mac just open Android Studio -> click Android Studio in the top bar -> click Prefrences -> find File and Code Templates in the list -> select includes -> build it and will be persistent in all your project

Answer (score 3):

- Another way to add java docs comment is press : **Ctrl + Shift + A**  >> show a popup >> type : Add javadocs >> Enter .
- Ctrl + Shirt + A: Command look-up (autocomplete command name)

[image]

Answer (score 3):

**Add Javadoc**

- `/**` + <kbd>return</kbd>
- set cursor inside method name -> <kbd>⌥ Option</kbd> + <kbd>return</kbd> -> Add Javadoc

Answer (score 2):

Simply select (i.e. click) the method name, then use the key combo Alt+Enter, select "Add JavaDoc"

This assumes that you have not already added comments above the method, else the "Add JavaDoc" option will not appear.

Answer (score 2):

In Android studio we have few ways to auto-generated comments:

- **Method I:**

By typing /** and Then pressing Enter you can generate next comment line and it will auto-generate the params, etc. but when you need the hotkey for this check out method II on below.

- **Method II: **

1 - Goto topMenu

2 - File > Settings

3 - Select Keymap from settings

4 - On the top right search bar search for "Fix Doc"

5 - Select the "fix doc comment" from the results and double-click on it

6 - Select Add keyboard shortcut from the opened drop down after double-click

7 - Press the shortcut keys on the keyboard

8 - Goto your code and where you want to add some comment press the shortcut key

9 - Enjoy!

Comment: The most convinuent way to add docs. E.g. I ve assigned " ' " and  Enter as the shortcut

Answer (score 1):

Just select the Eclipse version of the keycap in the Keymap settings.
An Eclipse Keymap is included in Android Studio.

Answer (score 1):

i recommendated [Dokka](https://github.com/Kotlin/dokka) for geneate javadoc with comment and more

Answer (score 1):

Because almost of us use `Kotlin`, you  can generate JavaDoc (KDoc) [using plugins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40574195/generate-kdoc-for-methods-in-android-studio). In Android Studio open `Settings` (press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>), select `Plugins` and find `kdoc`. I downloaded [KDoc-er](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/14778-kdoc-er--kotlin-doc-generator), but you can choose any of them. Then restart Android Studio.

Find any class/method, type `/**`, press <kbd>Enter</kbd>. You will get a short description like:

```
/**
 * User data
 *
 * @property name
 * @property avatar
 * @property gender
 * @constructor Create empty User data
 */
class UserData(...
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I completely understand the question, but a list of keyboard short cuts can be found [here](http://lirent.net/2013/05/android-studio-keyboard-shortcuts/) - Hope this helps!

Comment: In eclipse to add javadoc comments press Alt + shift + j, but in AndroidStudio but I don't know how to do

Comment: If I recall, that shortcut only worked if you had the 'jautodoc' plugin installed and enabled.

Answer (score 0):

Android Studio -> Preferences -> Editor -> Intentions -> Java -> Declaration -> Enable "Add JavaDoc"

And, While selecting Methods to Implement (Ctrl/Cmd + i), on the left bottom, you should be seeing checkbox to enable Copy JavaDoc.

Answer (score -1):

to generate javadoc comment use
/**
Your docs
*/

Comment: This has already been mentioned *and explained in detail* in the other answers. *When answering older questions that already have answers, please make sure you provide either a novel solution or a significantly better explanation than existing answers.*

Answer (score -5):

<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd> will create the auto generated comments for your method (place the cursor at starting position of your method).

Comment: public void hideKeyboard() u should place the cursor in front of public and try it or please check whether u installed the java doc in your studio.

Comment: It is not working for me either. Maybe, it is working in some special keymap. The keymap can be configured in Preferences > Keymap. Or the keymap has been edited.