# Add class and methods description for Android

Tags: android, performance, android-studio

I need to add description to my methods and classes a I don't know how to do it .

thanks in advance for helping!

Comment: Add descriptions? What did you exactly mean by that?

Comment: Are you referring to JavaDoc comments? http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_documentation.htm (and on [SO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17291785/how-to-generate-javadoc-comments-in-android-studio) )