# Android Studio JavaDocs do not generate

Tags: android, intellij-idea, javadoc, android-studio-2.1, block-comments

I started Android studio (2.1.2) today and when trying to add block comments using `/**` + <kbd>enter</kbd>, it is not generating the entire block with params and return statement.

I'm not sure what is causing this.

I tried googling the issue. But I'm unable to fix as of now with the solutions out there.

Please help me out to fix this issue.

Comment: Does [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29309454/1276636) help?

Comment: It's working now without any fix .. Weird .. Bloody studio .. don't know why.. Sorry guys..  Thanks @Sufian for ur response..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a Bug in Android studio.

If it is the last method in the class and you have some *commented block comments* below it, then you can't generate block comments.

Some thing like this:

```
{
  ......

    // You can't do a /** + enter here;
    // it won't generate JavaDoc if you do.
    public ViewPager getViewPager() {
        return mViewPager;
    }

    //  /*
    //   * Inner classes, interfaces, enums
    //   */
}
```

In this case, IDE doesn't generate block comment for `getViewPager()`.

Comment: The `/**` autogenerate works only on top of Class Constructors and Methods. And adding `//` to `/***/` seems kinda redundant. I would prefer to use only `/***/` if my comment is as long as paragraph, if it is single line I'll just use `//`.

Comment: Sorry, My explanation might have confused you. But if there is already a commented block comment at the end of class for some reason, then the auto block comment generation doesn't work for last method in the class.

Comment: Why you are adding `//` on `/**`? And basically `/**` has no effect when your methods has no arguments.

Comment: I'm not adding `//` as well, I just commented there for explaining. :)

Comment: Ah I see. Since your `getViewPager()` has no arguments at all, the `/**` will only provide `@return ViewPager` :) .

Comment: @sha the code snippet now seems all messed up. Why did you remove the `//`?

Comment: @sha read [this](http://tools.android.com/filing-bugs) and file this bug.

Comment: Thanks @Sufian. Filed a Bug - https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=215019

Comment: Still not fixed. June 2019. I shall send a note to the relevant body after checking if it's Google or IntelliJ.