# Is it possible to generate project wiki from Android Studio project?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I want to generate a project wiki for project in order to help newcomers. After a brief search I was not able to find any good solutions to do so from Android Studio.

What is a good way to active that, if your project is in Android Studio?

Thanks.

Comment: Android Studio does not provide this. The closest you have is a markdown plugin to maintain a readme.md but that is not full WIKI functionality. 
 Suggest you check if your source control application (GitHub?) can do it or look at a stand alone wiki.

Comment: @CodeChimp thank you, but maybe there are some scripts that can scan comments and generate wiki based on that? Like this one does for iOS https://github.com/realm/jazzy

Comment: Not a wiki but how you can generate javadocs from properly formatted comments via Gradle.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17033878/generate-javadocs-with-android-gradle-plugin  and   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17291785/how-to-generate-javadoc-comments-in-android-studio

Comment: @CodeChimp good, thanks, I'll upvote your comment :)